# How to parallelize C vectorized loops inside routines called from a parallel region in Fortran

Tags: c, multithreading, fortran, openmp

I have a Fortran code structured as below that calls C vectorized functions. I want to know the correct way to parallelize this code with OpenMP in order to avoid creating redundant threads for the loops inside the functions. I wrote a working version that uses "parallel for" before each for loop, but this version creates threads each time the functions are called, which is about billions of times, and I want to minimize the overhead of creating/destroying threads many times.

For this, I put the parallel region in the loop of the main program for routine sub1, the only one that needs parallelization. My doubt is if the subroutines and vectorized functions will be unnecessarily executed by each thread. How to make only the for loops run in parallel with threads created/destroyed in main program?

If you need more information about the code, please let me know.

```
program main

it=0
do while(it < nt)
    call sub0()
    !$omp parallel
    call sub1()
    !$omp end parallel
    call sub2()
    it=it+1
end do

end program main

subroutine sub1()
    t=0 ! this variable is global, so threadprivate is used in the Fortran module
    do while(t < dt)
        call sub1a(t0)
        call sub1b()
        t=t+t0
    end do
end subroutine sub1

subroutine sub1a()
    vecsub1ainC(vars) ! call to vectorized C function
    compute t0 with vars
    do more computations
end subroutine sub1a

vecsub1ainC(vars)
{
    // loop vectorized with Intel intrinsics
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        do computations with vars
    }
}

subroutine sub1b()
    vecsub1binC(vars) ! call to vectorized C function
    do more computations
end subroutine sub1b

vecsub1binC(vars)
{
    // loop vectorized with Intel intrinsics
    #pragma omp for
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        do computations with vars
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour]. I do not see any vectorization. Those "vectorized" loops use OpenMP threading/parallelization. I suggest to avoid the "vectorization" terminology to avoid confusion. Your code appears OK to me. Did you hit any problems?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Intel intrinsics on those C loops. The compilation error I get from the C code is "error: variable blabla in firstprivate or lastprivate clause of an OpenMP pragma must be shared in the enclosing context". From a Intel [reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag1392), it seems that firstprivate needs the parallel directive, but I want to define the parallel region in the main Fortran program, and then use #pragma omp for firstprivate(blabla), where blabla is a __m256 intrinsics variable declared in the C code.

Comment: If you have any error message, show it in the question by an [edit] and show the code that reproduces the error in the form of a [mcve]. We should ve able to compile the code and get the same error message.

Comment: As to the habit of using the term vectorization as a synonym for parallel intrinsics, that misleading usage seems to be a holdover from long-ago compilers which had no auto-vectorization, the most recent in widespread use being the Microsoft C++ of 10 years ago.

Comment: After some tests, I saw that the firstprivate clause was not necessary. As each thread calls the vectorized function, all variables declared inside the function will be local to the thread, so the intrinsics variable can be shared, and no data races will occur.